Can anyone provide a proof for the Super Symmetric Equation (SSE) using the uniqueness of analytic continuation?
Can anyone provide a proof for the Super Symmetric Equation (SSE) using the uniqueness of analytic continuation?
I’m currently studying the Super Symmetric Equation (SSE) in the context of the Riemann zeta function and would love to get some insights or a proof from the community. The equation is stated as:
$$
\zeta(s) = \zeta(1 - \bar{s})
$$
where $ \zeta(s) $ is the Riemann zeta function, and $ \bar{s} $ denotes the complex conjugate of $ s $.
This equation suggests that if the difference between the two series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 - \bar{s}}}
$$
converges to zero for some values of $ s $, then it must be true that:
$$
\zeta(s) = \zeta(1 - \bar{s})
$$
I’m particularly interested in understanding how this relates to the uniqueness of analytic continuation. Given that the Riemann zeta function is initially defined for $ \text{Re}(s) > 1 $, and can be analytically continued to the entire complex plane (except for $ s = 1 $), does the equality $ \zeta(s) = \zeta(1 - \bar{s}) $ imply that the analytic continuation of these two functions must be the same, and what are the implications for the zeros of the zeta function in the critical strip $ 0 < \text{Re}(s) < 1 $?
I’m still exploring this idea and would greatly appreciate any formal proofs or insights from those with expertise in analytic continuation, especially regarding its application to the zeta function. I’m open to all constructive feedback and suggestions!
Looking forward to learning more from the community!
